# python list of numbers to string

Tags: python, string, list

I wanted to make a list of strings ['0010','0020', ..., '0100']

I couldn't understand why two different expressions

```
>>> ["%04d" % i*10 for i in range(11)]
['', '0010', '00100010', '001000100010', '0010001000100010',
'00100010001000100010', '001000100010001000100010',
'0010001000100010001000100010', '00100010001000100010001000100010',
'001000100010001000100010001000100010',
'0010001000100010001000100010001000100010']

>>> ["%04d" % (i*10) for i in range(11)]
['0000', '0010', '0020', '0030', '0040', '0050',
'0060', '0070', '0080', '0090', '0100']
```

give different results.

Can someone explain what is going on here?

Comment: [Operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html). Also `format(i * 10, '04d')` is probably better

Answer (score 1):

Yeah, this doesn't have anything to do with the conversion to string- you're doing

```
 (x % i) * 10
```

in one case and

```
x % (i * 10)
```

in the other because of the parentheses

Answer (score 1):

BODMAS ..

BODMAS stands for Brackets, Order, Divide, Multiply, Add, Subtract

in the first expression..

```
["%04d" % i*10 for i in range(11)]
```

it is doing 10 times of "%04d" % i .

in the second expression..

```
["%04d" % (i*10) for i in range(11)]
```

it is doing what is meaningful.

Comment: Hi can I know who is up voting?

Answer (score 0):

the first is equivelant to

```
[("%04d" % i) * 10 for i in range(11)]
```